# The Asian countries calculate Pi!

Tags: knowledge, story

The Asian countries convened to try and see if their new computer, the *Singapore 9000*, with **2 bits** of RAM, (in their defense, it was a secondhand computer) could calculate pi.

China punched the request in.

Then, the United Arab Emirates punched it in, saying it wasn’t specific enough.

Then, Indonesia punched it in… and it overestimated.

They all complained at Indonesia, so he went to the reasonable adult, the U.N., and he said:

“Oh, that’s cute! You’re trying to calculate… and that dial is set wrong, which is why it didn’t work!”

In a rare lapse of character, Indonesia fell asleep during the lecture. Being their resident handyman, when it failed again, he didn’t know what to do. But… he could know HOW it was breaking…

**HOW is the *Singapore 9000* breaking when Indonesia punches in his request?**

Comment: It's quite possible that I'm missing the point, but shouldn't that be two bytes of RAM, not two bits?

Comment: @KenShirriff I think the point of 2 bits is not that it's data, rather that it's 2 pieces of information

Comment: if instead of United Arab Emirates the British Indian Ocean Territory could mount backward you might could get some development aid from Belgian to get further

Comment: Eh, the whole point was only Asian countries. I wonder how close you could get with other continents….

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all

> Let us look at the two letter [ISO 3166 country codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_3166_country_codes) for the countries involved.
>  China is **CN**.
>  UAE is **AE**.
>  Indonesia is **ID**.
>  Converting these into numbers using an alphanumeric cipher (A=1, B=2, C=3,...) we have
>  CN = 3,14
>  AE = 1,5
>  ID = 9,4

So presumably

> Using this method, after China punches the request in, the estimate is **3.14**.
>  UAE says that isn't specific enough and adds its **1,5** to give **3.1415** - a better estimate.
>  When Indonesia punches in, it adds **9,4** which yields **3.141594** - a slight overestimate of $\pi$.

The problem is

> Any other country which tries to add to this will give a worse estimate of $\pi$ than is already present.

The UN is probably explaining that

> **IZ** would have resulted in a much better estimate. Maybe the additional **Z** sent Indonesia to sleep.

I'm unsure if

> There is more to it than this - Indonesia's code gives the best estimate as there isn't a country with ISO code **IB** or **IC**

OP’S EDIT:

> Yes! This is correct. the U.N. explained that using their internet domains (they’re the same as the ISO codes for the most part) wouldn’t work. Maybe next time they should try phone codes… *evil cackling* I’m sorry for not cluing in the A1Z26, however.